# not able to perform wireless connection on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I am having ubuntu 12.04 machine,i was not able to access via wireless network connection. Now, the machine is connected via wired connection. Please share me the details how to turn ubuntu 12.04 in to wireless connecting device

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- connect your machine wired to the internet
- make shure you have a good internet-connection (e.g. start up your browser and check for a random page)
- go to the right corner (up) and click the little radar
- Open up your system-settings
- look under HARDWARE for the 'extra drivers' (an icon with a pc-card and a little lock)
- run this program and let it search for an additional driver.
- if one found install this driver (click for it)

I always advise a full reboot after this operation (so the driver is certainly loaded) 
Establish a WIFI-connection (mind for the password) and it should work fine. You can do that via the networkmanager. This is an icon in your taskbar at the upper hand. 
Check if any networks in your neighbourhood are detected. Select your network (these have a name or digits or combined) click on that and typ in your password; now you should have a WIFI-connection.

If there is no driver (additional) found, I'd suggest you open a new question followed with information of your hardware (any info is fine) .

I hope for succes !